# Error shifting a binary number in Verilog

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, binary

I want to shift a binary number, for example 001011010 to 101101000 or 0000111001 to 1110010000. I wrote Verilog code but getting error.

```
module test(b,a);
output [8:0]b;
input [8:0]a;
genvar i;
for(i=8;i>=0;i=i-1) begin
    if(a[i]==1) begin
        assign b=a<<(8-i);
    end
end
endmodule

module t;
reg [8:0]a;
wire [8:0]b;
test g(.a(a),.b(b));
initial begin
    $monitor("time=%g a=%b b=%b",$time,a,b);
    a=001011010; #20 a=000000110;
end
endmodule
```

an error occured as shown:

```
test.v:6: error: Unable to bind parameter `a[i]' in `t.g.$gen1[5]'
```

Comment: Describe in words what you are trying to do. The 1st example shifts left by 2 bits, the 2nd by 4 bits. What is the general rule?

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax is illegal.  It looks like you are using `iverilog` as a simulator; however, the error message is not very helpful.

You can run your code on different simulators on [EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/GEFa) to get a slightly more helpful error message.  For example:

```
    if(a[i]==1) begin
       |
xmvlog: *E,NOTPAR (testbench.sv,6|7): Illegal operand for constant expression [4(IEEE)].
```

You are misusing the `generate` construct.  The expression `a[i]` is a variable expression, but it must be a constant expression.

I always find it useful to unroll `for` loops when debugging syntax errors like this.  For example, the `generate` `for` loop can be expanded like:

```
module test(b,a);
output [8:0]b;
input [8:0]a;

    if(a[8]==1) begin
        assign b = a<<0;
    end

    if(a[7]==1) begin
        assign b = a<<1;
    end

  // etc.

endmodule
```

This is also illegal, but it makes it clearer *why* it is illegal.  Each `if` block is interpreted as though it has `generate/endgenerate` keywords (which are optional) around it.  The problem is that `a[8]` must be a constant value, not a variable.

---

There is an unrelated mistake in your code.  In the `t` module, you need to use the `'b` prefix for your assignments to `a` if you want the numeric constants to be interpreted in binary format.  Change:

```
a=001011010; #20 a=000000110;
```

to:

```
a='b001011010; #20 a='b000000110;
```

---

If you are looking to shift `a` by a variable number of bits, you could add another `input` port (`c`):

```
module test (
    output [8:0]b,
    input [8:0]a,
    input [3:0]c
);
    assign b = a<<c;
endmodule

module t;
reg [8:0]a;
reg [3:0]c;
wire [8:0]b;
test g(.a(a),.b(b),.c(c));
initial begin
    $monitor("time=%g a=%b b=%b",$time,a,b);
    c=2;
    a='b001011010; #20 a='b000000110;
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

From the examples in your question and your code, I'm assuming you want to shift the leading one in your input to the MSB bit. To do this you would use a leading one detector (LOD) followed by a shifter (or barrel shifter).

```verilog
module test (
    output [8:0] b,
    input  [8:0] a,
);

    wire [3:0] lod_out, shift;
  
    // Leading one detector
    // Your LOD code goes in lead_one_det module
    // lod_out gives the bit position of the leading one in 'a' wrt LSB

    lead_one_det  LOD(.input(a), .lod_output(lod_out));
    assign shift = 4'h8 - lod_out;      // Shift is wrt MSB

    // Shifter
    assign b = a << (shift);

endmodule
```

I've not written down the code for the LOD. You should be able to find plenty of examples for it online.